# Preventing UITableView from scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

This seems like it'd be a common question, so apologies if it's been asked before.

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent UITableView from scrolling in my iPhone application altogether.  I want my table to be vertically locked, so that no amount of screen swiping will cause it to move.

How do I implement this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do that from your XIB as well as programmatically.

**From XIB:**

Just select the tableView and in Inspector uncheck bounce horizontally & bounce vertically and scroll horizontally and scroll vertically

**Programmatically:**

If you want to do that programmatically  then you can try

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

OR

```
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

UITableView is inherited from UIScrollView so Use scrollEnabled property of UIScrollView

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView

Comment: @Julia :How do you know who posted before ?.....Suggest you to check the time of post and i know the rest thanks.

Comment: @Julia: the link to the documentation and the brief discussion of inheritance, neither of which appear in PARTH's answer, make this answer also valuable.