# How to make two table views in a utility application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've been trying to have two tables in a utility application but I'm having problems; when I create two delegates and two data sources I'm getting an error. Is there a way to make multiple delegates in one class?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Trim down your code to a sample that can be easily posted so we can see what you've tried already, and also post the actual error messages you are receiving. Otherwise we have little hope of being able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you cannot put two delegates and two datsource for two tables in same view controller.

You can use a flag or a hidden UILabel where in you set the unique value and access datasource and delegates based on the value of flag or label.

**For Example:**

If I have 2 tables, one for **Buy** and one for **Sale**

I will set UILabel named say **tableIdentifier**

```
tableIdentifier.text = @"Buy";
```

when I want to load the **Buy** table

and similarly set

```
tableIdentifier.text = @"Sale";
```

when I want to load the **Sale** table

Now as far as datasource and delegate methods are concerned, this is how it goes:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     int rows = 0;
      if([tableIdentifier.text isEqualToString:@"Buy"])
      {
          rows = //Your row count for Buy;
      }
      else if([tableIdentifier.text isEqualToString:@"Sale"])
      {
           rows = //Your row count for Sale;
      }

     return rows;
 }
```

Similarly it works for each of the delegate and datasource methods based on the value of label or flag.

**Note:**

If you use a label as I have shown above then you need to `outlet` that label to a hidden label in XIB and `@synthesize` the label, otherwise its value will return null in the case if the value is not retained.

Hope this helps you

**EDIT:**

In that case you can take the count as `[plist1Array count] + [plist2Array count]` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` method

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can check for indexPath.row and load data based on that

```
if(indexPath.row <=[plist1Array count])
{
     //Load data in cell.textLabel.text From `plist1Array`
}
else if(indexPath.row >[plist1Array count] && indexPath.row <[plist2Array count])
{
    //Load data in cell.textLabel.text From `plist2Array`
}
```

**EDIT-1:**

If you want you can just show them in different sections of the same table rather than showing them in two different tables like

In `numberOfRowsInSection:` method

```
 int j = 0;
 if(indexPath.section == 0)
 {
      j=[plist1Array count];
 }
 else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
 {
      j=[plist2Array count];
 }
 return j;
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
     //Load data in cell.textLabel.text From `plist1Array`
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
{
    //Load data in cell.textLabel.text From `plist2Array`
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @PARTH: What did i miss out that lead you to put your own answer ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response ...Actually i have two table views in my view and each table is taking the data from different plists.I want to display both data at the same time when the program loads.I only know how to display it in one table not in the two tables.Because i am using only one delegate and data source dont know how to use multiple delegates .

Comment: @Jhaliya: Actually may be you didnt miss out on anything but I was typing my answer while you posted it. I can ask you the same question with respect to this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343969/preventing-uitableview-from-scrolling/5344072#5344072   but anyways leave it as there is no point in arguing.

Comment: @user665427: You are Welcome.. I have edited my answer. Please check `EDIT` section of my answer. If you still need any help. you can just leave a comment here

Comment: @PARTH :The reason for commenting out your post was your mentioned reference (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343969/preventing-uitableview-from-scrolling/5344072#5344072). The same happened with the referenced post as with this.Anyway let it go,We can't get anything out of this argument,lets maintain a healthy environment here and keep posting answer Thanks.

Comment: @Jhaliya: Yeah. I am Sorry for this post. Nothing Personal :-) Keep answering :-)

Comment: @user665427: Did the `EDIT` section of my answer help you? Also check out `EDIT-1` in my answer

Comment: @user665427: Can you please tell what is the requirement to use two different tables when you can seperate out the data in two sections of the same table? If you use two sections of the same table then your problem of multiple datasource and delegates will be solved more easily.Just think about it. Do let me know if you have more doubts on this

Answer (score 1):

Keep the single occurence of your Delegate and datasource functions.

Just use the below approach and put in the beginning of each function (Just Sample).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        if(myTableOne == tableView)  
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if(myTableSecond == tableView)
       {
          return 10;
       }
}
```