# How to create an immovable TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I would like to create a Sign Up page in my application and I want to create an immovable table(witch you can not scroll). I'm doing this in Swift language, if somebody knows will be very helpful. [Sign Up Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdE6N.png)

Comment: this is very common question, please search properties and search in google before post question.

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector window of the tableview storyboard turn off anything related to scrolling.  And then just make sure your table view height does not exceed the view height

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [bounces property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html) to NO?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
tableView.bounces = false
tableView.scrollEnabeld = false
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344072/4882590

You can do that from your XIB as well as programmatically.

From XIB:

> Just select the tableView and in Inspector uncheck bounce horizontally & bounce vertically and scroll horizontally and scroll vertically

Programmatically:

If you want to do that programmatically then you can try

> self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false

OR

> [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

Comment: Instead of quoting an answer from another question, you should vote to close this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I did @rmaddy . On the other hand, I was also willing to help.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate actually is helping.

Comment: Yes, and I did that too.

Comment: But that's the problem. If you vote to close, you should not also post an answer. It defeats the purpose and it is bad form because it makes you appear to be posting solely to get reputation. Pointing the user to the other question is enough to help. No need to post a duplicate answer to a duplicate question.